# Convergence $\sum \frac {1} {k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n=\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + .....+\frac{1}{n^2}\;\forall n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$. Prove that $a_n \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n} \;\forall n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$.Deduce the convergence of ${a_n}$.

I have proved the inequality using mathematical induction. But I'm stucked at proving the convergence of $\{a_n\}$. Please help.

Comment: Use that $2-1/n\to2$ as $n\to\infty$ and that $a_n$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Cf. [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_{n}=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}$. Note that $\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}$ is smaller than $\dfrac{1}{k(k-1)}$ for positive integer $k$ if $k$ is not $1$. So $a_{n}$ is smaller than $1+\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^{n} \left(\dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k}\right)=2-\dfrac{1}{n}$. This proves inequality.

Since $2-\dfrac{1}{n}$ is bounded above, so does $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}>0$. Therefore It is increasing sequence. By Monotone convergence theorem, $a_{n}$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence increases and bounded above by $2$ hence converges.